# Boundary of a set difference

Tags: real-analysis

If we have any two sets $E,F$, how do i show $∂(E$ \ $F ) ⊂ ∂E ∪ ∂F$, i.e. the boundary of $E$ \ $F$ is a subset of union of boundary $E$ and boundary $F$?

I have proved that $∂(E ∪ F ) ⊂ ∂E ∪ ∂F$ and it just seems intuitive that the set difference is obviously true but I cannot seem to derive it using the same way I proved it for union through the property Boundary is Intersection of Closure with Closure of Complement.

Comment: I have already made one comment about your misuse of the set theory tags. I did not think I would have to make another. Please stop using them for questions that have nothing to do with set theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\partial (E\backslash F) \subset \partial E \cup \partial F$ can be deduced from $\partial (E\cup F) \subset \partial E \cup \partial F$ and the fact that $\partial A = \partial A^c$ for any set $A$.

$$ (E\backslash F )^c = F \cup E^c$$
so $$\partial (E\backslash F) = \partial (F \cup E^c) \subset \partial F \cup \partial E^c = \partial E \cup \partial F$$